# How to initialize thread local variable in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, thread-local, thread-local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++11 thread_local in gcc - alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142453/c11-thread-local-in-gcc-alternatives)
>   [Is there any way to fully emulate thread_local using GCC's __thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063073/is-there-any-way-to-fully-emulate-thread-local-using-gccs-thread)

I wanted to use the c++11 `thread_local` to create and use thread_local variable but as it is not yet supported by gcc, I am using gcc specific `__thread`. The way I declared the variable is

```
myClass
{
public:

  static __thread int64_t m_minInt;

};
__thread int64_t myClass::m_minInt = 100;
```

When I compile it, I get an error like

```
error: ‘myClass::minInt’ is thread-local and so cannot be dynamically initialized
```

How to properly do it?

PS: gcc version: 4.6.3

Comment: @betabandido the question you linked discusses the alternative to thread_local in c++11. My question is how to use __thread from gcc. Specifically the error message in question. I tried to find it elsewhere but could not get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use lazy initialization.

```
myClass
{
public:

  static __thread int64_t m_minInt;
  static __thread bool m_minIntInitialized;

  static int64_t getMinInt();
};
__thread int64_t myClass::m_minInt;
__thread bool myClass::m_minIntInitialized;


int64_t myClass::getMinInt()
{
  if (!m_minIntInitialized)  // note - this is (due to __thread) threadsafe
  {
    m_minIntInitialized = true;
    m_minInt = 100;
  }

  return m_minInt;
}
```

`m_minIntInitialized` is guaranteed to be zero.

In most cases ([ELF specification](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf)) it is placed to .tbss section, which is zero-initialized.

For C++ - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

> For all other non-local static and thread-local variables, Zero
>   initialization takes place. In practice, variables that are going to
>   be zero-initialized are placed in the .bss segment of the program
>   image, which occupies no space on disk, and is zeroed out by the OS
>   when loading the program.

Comment: How do you know m_minIntInitialized is initially false?

Comment: @CygnusX1, I've updated the answer.

Comment: You have a race condition: other thread can read m_minInt after the flag is set to true but before the variable is initialized;

Comment: @gdy, how can possibly other thread interfere with thread local variable?

Comment: @Yossarian, oh, right