# Thread local storage constructor g++

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, thread-local

As non trivial thread local storage variables have an overhead, I would like to use the `__attribute__((constructor))` indication on some function in order to initialize thread local data ( being intended that the function will be called each time a thread starts ).
Is that some how possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `__attribute__((constructor))` in that manner.  There is no option to designate a function to be called by TLS automatically each time a new thread starts.  You will have to code it manually using [lazy initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075492/65863) instead.